# Image conversion from IFF and EXR formats to JPEG format

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using `convert Desktop/iff_image.iff Desktop/iff_image.jpg` to convert my images to JPEG format.

But getting as

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `Desktop/iff_image.iff' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/552.
convert: no images defined `Desktop/iff_image.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3127.
```

For .tif, .tiff, .cin, .dpx extensions it is working properly.

The issue is coming only for .iff and .exr extensions.

Answer (score 3):

### IFF

I am not familiar with a format named 'IFF'. Sorry to be of no help for this one...

### EXR

For support of reading and writing the EXR format, your ImageMagick installation needs to have...

1. ...access to the [OpenEXR](http://www.openexr.org/) library (which also must be installed on your system);
2. ...been built with support for the OpenEXR *delegate*.

In ImageMagick, 'delegates' are external programs or helper utilities which support ImageMagick to handle formats which it cannot handle on its own.

One of the most common delegates found in ImageMagick is *Ghostscript*. Ghostscript is required to process PDF or PostScript input files, because ImageMagick can only handle *raster formats*. So Ghostscript converts PDFs and PS to raster images on behalf of ImageMagick, then hands over these raster data to IM, which then does the rest of the required work.

To print the list of all built-in delegates, run this command (on Linux or Mac OS X):

```
convert -version | grep Delegates
```

The respective Windows command is:

```
convert -version | findstr Delegates
```

The output I see on my system for this command is this:

```
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc jbig \
                      jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png   \
                      ps rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

The list of supported delegates should have `openexr` amongst them. If it is not there, you need to install a version of ImageMagick that has it.

To check which compile-time options have been used to build your version of ImageMagick, run

```
 convert -list configure
```

If the linen starting `DELEGATES` does not list `openexr`, the binary package for your system has not been built with OpenEXR in mind. If it ***is*** listed, but still not working, something else is wrong...

On my system, I see this:

```
Path: /opt/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.0//config-Q16/configure.xml

Name           Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CC             /usr/bin/clang
CFLAGS         -I/opt/local/include/lqr-1 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 \
               -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/opt/local/include \
               -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include \
               -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -pipe -Os -arch x86_64 \
               -Wall -march=corei7-avx -fexceptions -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 \
               -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 \
               -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
CODER_PATH     /opt/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.0/modules-Q16/coders
CONFIGURE      ./configure  '--prefix=/opt/local' '--enable-shared' \
                  '--enable-static' '--disable-ltdl-install' \
                  '--disable-silent-rules' '--with-frozenpaths' \
                  '--with-openexr' '--disable-hdri' '--with-dps' \
                  '--with-bzlib' '--with-djvu' '--with-fontconfig' \
                  '--with-gslib' '--with-jbig' '--with-jpeg' '--with-lcms' \
                  '--with-openjp2' '--with-png' '--with-tiff' '--with-webp' \
                  '--with-zlib' '--with-modules' '--with-xml' \
                  '--without-perl' '--without-fpx' '--with-wmf' \
                  '--with-gvc' '--with-rsvg' '--with-lqr' '--with-pango' \
                  '--with-x' '--with-gs-font-dir=/opt/local/share/fonts/urw-fonts' \
                  'CC=/usr/bin/clang' 'CFLAGS=-pipe -Os -arch x86_64' \
                  'LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names \
                  -arch x86_64' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include' \
                  'CXX=/usr/bin/clang++' 'CXXFLAGS=-pipe -Os -arch x86_64 \
                  -stdlib=libc++'
CONFIGURE_PATH /opt/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/
COPYRIGHT      Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
CPPFLAGS       -I/opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6
CXX            /usr/bin/clang++
CXXFLAGS       -pipe -Os -arch x86_64 -stdlib=libc++ -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
DEFS           -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DELEGATES      bzlib djvu mpeg fftw fontconfig freetype gslib jbig jng jpeg lcms \
               lqr lzma openexr openjp2 pango png ps rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS 'CC=/usr/bin/clang' 'CFLAGS=-pipe -Os -arch x86_64' \
               'CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include' 'CXX=/usr/bin/clang++' \
               'LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names \
                -arch x86_64' --disable-deprecated --with-quantum-depth=16 \
                --with-jemalloc=no --with-umem=no --with-autotrace=no \
                --with-fpx=no --with-fontpath= --with-gs-font-dir=/opt/local/share/fonts/urw-fonts \
                --with-perl=no
DOCUMENTATION_PATH /opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6
EXEC-PREFIX    /opt/local
EXECUTABLE_PATH /opt/local/bin
FEATURES       DPC Modules
FILTER_PATH    /opt/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.0/modules-Q16/filters
HOST           x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
INCLUDE_PATH   /opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6
LDFLAGS        -L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names \
               -arch x86_64 -L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib
LIB_VERSION    0x690
LIB_VERSION_NUMBER 6,9,0,0
LIBRARY_PATH   /opt/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.0
LIBS           -llcms2 -L/opt/local/lib -lfreetype -L/opt/local/lib -llqr-1 \
               -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lfftw3 -L/opt/local/lib -lfontconfig -lfreetype \
               -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -L/opt/local/lib -llzma -lbz2 -lz \
               -lltdl -lm
NAME           ImageMagick
PCFLAGS        -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
PREFIX         /opt/local
QuantumDepth   16
RELEASE_DATE   2014-12-06
SHARE_PATH     /opt/local/share/ImageMagick-6
SHAREARCH_PATH /opt/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.0/config-Q16
SVN_REVISION   17068
TARGET_CPU     x86_64
TARGET_OS      darwin13.4.0
TARGET_VENDOR  apple
VERSION        6.9.0
WEBSITE        http://www.imagemagick.org

Path: [built-in]

Name           Value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
FEATURES       
NAME           ImageMagick
QuantumDepth   16
```