# convert EXR to PNG using Rust

Tags: rust, png, openexr

Hello I wanted to convert OpenEXR format file to png file.

I found [this example](https://github.com/johannesvollmer/exrs/blob/master/examples/1b_convert_exr_to_png.rs) from exr crates and ran code. However, the result of converted png file has different color from the original.

EXR file : [image]

Converted Png file:

[image]

Image crate also has [save_with_format](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.save_with_format), but the result was also different from the original.

Is there any other way to convert exr to png file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a known problem on conversion from EXR to PNG.
It is even written in the TODO of the example

```rust
// TODO does the `image` crate expect gamma corrected data?
```

Though i don't know if any crate can automatically fix this, or if there is a good solution to automatically calculating gammas, you could try invoking imagemagick like this post
[How do I convert EXR to PNG and adjust brightness at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966819/how-do-i-convert-exr-to-png-and-adjust-brightness-at-the-same-time)